# How do I remove the white area in Bootstrap 3's external modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Boostrap 3.2.0's remote modal, but it makes some kind of white window in the background - how can I remove it?

Modal.html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="Modal-Content.html" data-target="#MyModal">Modal Popup</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="MyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- // -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal-Content.html:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal Preview</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some external content here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Remote Boostrap Modal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a modal inside your modal, try:

```
<!-- Modal.html: -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="Modal-Content.html" data-target="#MyModal">Modal Popup</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="MyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- // -->
        </div>
     </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal-Content.html: -->
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal Preview</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some external content here.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```